# How to obtain reference to TextField in UI Tests in Xcode 7

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode7, xcode-ui-testing, uitest

I am trying to use UI tests in Xcode 7  beta.
I have a storyboard with two text fields. Both text fields have outlets and different Restoration IDs. I recorded the test but generated code is quite unreadable and it doesn't work:

```
app.otherElements.containingType(.TextField, identifier:"y").childrenMatchingType(.TextField).elementBoundByIndex(0).typeText("hello")
```

I also tried the following and will work based on Placeholder text?!?

```
app.textFields["PlaceholderText"].typeText("hello")
```

What is the right way to obtain a reference to a TextField in UI tests?

Comment: Which beta are you on?

Comment: This question was for beta 4; just uploaded to beta 5.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You need to set accessibility identifier in storyboard for that particular textField. Check the image below :

[image]

So you can query textField using accessibility identifier like this :

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
app.launch()

let nameTextField = app.textFields["nameTextField"]
nameTextField.tap()
nameTextField.typeText("Hello John")
```

Comment: What if that is in an array, so there are two or more onscreen at once? Is there any way to find one by its current text?

Comment: Are there any way to find by placeholder? without the accesibility identifier?